# How to combine custom fields to make one order-able value

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I have three different custom fields, for day (01-07) hour (01-12) and minute (00-59) and I really need to combine them into one custom value so I can actually order them using wp_query.

I cant actually just use custom field for the whole thing; it would be easier I know, but it needs to be easy on the user to input day/time. So that option is out of the question.

Is it possible to join those three numerical values for use in wp_query?

Thanks in advance for any help.

David

Comment: What the user fills out need not look like what you put into the database. Give the user whatever form you think is best but save to the database in a format usable to PHP, MySQL, and WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it as easy as possible on the user, then I think the best option would be to [add a custom meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) with three fields for inputting the day/hour/minute values. Using something like a jQuery UI slider style timepicker would further simplify input. Then when the post is saved, use the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action to store those three values in a single field.

The second option is similar to the first, but you'd continue using the custom fields as you are now, except a fourth field would be added by you on the `save_post` action to combine them into a single field you use in your query.